# Add timeout to MKDirectionsRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am using following code to calculate route between two points. I want to add a timeout to the request. Couldn't find any method to set timeout for the request.

```
MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
[request setSource:sourceMapItem];
[request setDestination:destMapItem];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeWalking]; //Change Here
[request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:YES];


MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // do your thing here
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

a workaround: Create a timer and decide showing/not showing the route when the calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler is completed according to your timer's current value.

---

I don't know why you need the timeout but in my case I had a collection view and when user scrolls i show the route to the current map item.

and i had multiple routes on map when user scrolling so fast.

What i implement was using a timer before doing the route request (so that if user is scrolling route search won't start immediately will start in time but will be canceled if user switches to another map item)

What also could be implemented is to cancel the MKDirectionsRequest. But it does not work if isCalculating = true:

```
// Any calls to -calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler: or calculateETAWithCompletionHandler
// while -[MKDirections isCalculating] will fail. completionHandler will be called on the main queue
public func calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: MKDirectionsHandler)
public func calculateETAWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: MKETAHandler)
public func cancel()
```

So if you want to aim to kill the handler event when the response is there, what you could do is to check the latest item

```
if let _ = response where (mapItem == self?.latestMapItem) {
    self?.showRoute(response!, itemLocation: mapItem)
    self?.routeInfoView.hidden = false
}
```